# How to translate a normal application to a pipe or compose

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, function-composition

I have a function with two arguments. For the sake of simplicity let's assume it just subtracts the numbers. I want to flip and curry its arguments. I have figured out how to do it manually, but it really feels like it could be done with pipe or compose and I can't figure out how.

```
import { curry, flip, pipe } from 'ramda';

const subtract = (a, b) => a - b; // subtract(1, 4); -3
const flippedCurriedSubtract = flip(curry(subtract))
// flippedCurriedSubtract(1)(4); 3

pipe(flip, curry, subtract)(1)(4); // NaN
```

How would you do that with `pipe` or `compose`?

**EDIT:**

```
pipe(
    curry,
    flip
)(subtract); // works
```

Comment: [`flip` itself](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/flip.js#L26-L31) curries the result.  So `flip((a, b) => a - b)` will work as hoped.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Wow, that is actually the best answer.

Comment: Here at Ramda, we aim to please!  Or at least please ourselves! ;-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm learning to love the library (and fp) more and more. It reduces code (and therefore bug surfaces) so much  Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pipe(flip, curry, subtract)(1)(4)` is equal to `subtract(curry(flip(1)(4)))`

Meanwhile definition of `flip`:

```
// flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c 
const flip = curry((fn, a, b) => fn(b, a));
```

It mean `flip` function will recieve a `curry` function (a -> b -> c) as a parameter, but now it a number then cause error.

`pipe(curry,flip)(subtract)` is equal to `flip(curry(subtract))` and this will fit.
It also returns the same with `.compose(flip, curry)(subtract)`. `compose` and `pipe` is the same just different about the direction execute function.

And for the newbie. I recommend you to read this [ebook](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/)

Comment: I read that and did the assignments. Very good book. Now I'm trying to apply what I've learned in real life. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know most functions in Ramda are curried already. So you don't need to curry subtract again.

```
subtract(5, 10); //=> -5
subtract(5)(10); //=> -5
```

You can `flip` it, it will still be curried:

```
flip(subtract)(5, 10); //=> 5
flip(subtract)(5)(10); //=> 5
```

I don't think you need pipe and curry at all, you could simply do:

```
const flippedSubtract = flip(subtract);
flippedSubtract(5)(10); //=> 5
```

Scott pointed out in the comments that `flip` will automatically curry a non-curried function: (very helpful)

```
const foo = (a, b, c) => `foo: ${a}${b}${c}`;
foo('x', 'y', 'z');       //=> 'foo: xyz'
flip(foo)('x')('y')('z'); //=> 'foo: yxz'
```

Comment: `subtract` was just an example. In the real world I have my own function (that is too long for this question). I specified my own `subtract` as an example because subtractions aren't commutative. I guess I should've used another function to avoid confusion with Ramda's `subtract`.

Comment: Ah sure, in that case you'd need to compose curry and flip indeed.

Comment: [`flip` itself](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/flip.js#L26-L31) curries the result.  So `flip(myNonCommutativeFunction)` will work as hoped.